# Delete child object from parent object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

seemed like a simple task but im finding it hard to achive.
I have object containing child objects, and while looping over them i would like to delete an inner object in based on value of one of it's fields (this field exists in every inner object).

the loop goes like this:

```
for (let old_item of this.updated_items) {
    if (old_item['content_id'] === item.content_id) {
        this.updated_items.***DELETE***(old_item)
    }
}
```

I marked location where is the missing logic.
How would i delete `old_item` from `this.updated_items`?
ES6 if possible..thx

Comment: can u please show your html?

Comment: What do you mean by delete? delete from array / replace by undefined / do a dom deletion ?

Comment: What exactly is `this.updated_items`? An array, a `Map`? Without that information it's impossible to answer the question. All you've shown is that it is iterable.

Comment: sorry guess i wasn't clear in my title, both `typeof()`'s of `this.updated_items` and its content...which are the items, equal to `Object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate the [Object#entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and when the correct `content_id` is found on the value, delete the key from the original object.

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.updated_items)) {
    if (value.content_id === item.content_id) {
        delete this.updated_items[key];
    }
}
```

Since Object#entries is not supported by some browsers, another option is to use Array#forEach to iterate the object's keys, and if the `content_id` is found delete the key from the original object:

```
Object.keys(this.updated_items) // get the object's keys
    .forEach((key) => // iterate the keys
                this.updated_items[key].content_id === item.content_id // if the content id is similar
                && 
                delete this.updated_items[key] //delete the key from the original object
     )
```

Comment: I'm not sure using `delete` keyword is what OP meant

Comment: As far as I understand it, he wants to remove a property from an object, and delete is the way to do so. If he thinks otherwise, he'll select another answer :)

Comment: You also don't need to use `Object.entries` but just a `for...of` should do the trick (if browser support it)

Comment: For of needs an iterable and object is not an iterable.

Comment: Yeah I just tried it and saw my mistake... However I saw somewhere that there is another than object.entries that is better on MDN. Let me look at it and come back to you if found :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`filter`](//mdn.io/array.filter) function over an array, and convert your object to an array using [`Array.from`](//mdn.io/array.from):

```
this.update_items = Array.from(this.updated_items).fiter(old_item => old_item.content_id !== item.content_id)
```

Comment: It's not an array, it's an object containing child objects (I posted more or less the same answer before realizing this)

Comment: Oh ok, Maybe then using [`Array.from`](//mdn.io/array.from) would solve this issue

Comment: I don't know OPs case, but it works with a list of node elements (for instance by calling `myOl.children`)